# Angular 2 not working on Safari 9.1.2

Tags: javascript, angular, safari, polyfills

Well it seems that angular is not working at all with safari, everything worked perfectly using chrome and firefox until I tested my application on safari. With no working I mean, ngModel, ngIf and so on, nothing works, neither animations.
So I think there must be an issue with polyfills, but I'm not sure. Did someone experienced something like that?

In my polyfills file I have the following:

```
import "es6-shim";
import "core-js/es6/symbol";
import "core-js/es6/object";
import "core-js/es6/function";
import "core-js/es6/parse-int";
import "core-js/es6/parse-float";
import "core-js/es6/number";
import "core-js/es6/math";
import "core-js/es6/string";
import "core-js/es6/date";
import "core-js/es6/array";
import "core-js/es6/regexp";
import "core-js/es6/map";
import "core-js/es6/set";
import "core-js/es6/weak-map";
import "core-js/es6/weak-set";
import "core-js/es6/typed";
import "core-js/es6/reflect";

import "core-js/es7/observable";
import "core-js/es7/reflect";
import "core-js/es7/system";
import "core-js/es7/array";
import "zone.js/dist/zone";
import "zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone"; // Internet Explorer 9 support
```

I'm using Angular 4.1.3 by the way.

Comment: Have you gone through this yet? https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: @wannadream Yeah, but didn't work with any of those polyfills.

Comment: I have the same issue on safari 9.3

Comment: @Vercryger have you solved it? The same issue with 9.1. All polyfills turned on, Angular 4.4.5. Safari 8 works and Safari 10 works as expected.

Comment: @Mike Yeah I solved it by changing angular versions, don't ask me what version because that was a nightmare I can't even remember, sorry about that. But I decided to move react.js anyway.

Comment: @Vercryger I've set versions of Angular to 4.4.6, rxjs to 5.5.2, typescript to 2.4.2, removed ngrx, and Safari 9.1.3 seems to start working well.